# How to avoid defunct python processes in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

With python3 (3.4.3) on Ubuntu 14.04 I have created a `Forker` class which I use in two different processes to create child processes. Here is the `Forker` class:

```
class Forker(object):
    def __init__(self):     
        self.active_children = []            

    def reap_children(self):                              
        while self.active_children:                        
            pid,stat = os.waitpid(0, os.WNOHANG)       
            if not pid: break
            self.active_children.remove(pid)                

    def fork(self, function, *args, **kwargs):         
        self.reap_children()

        child_pid = os.fork()
        if child_pid == 0:
            function(*args, **kwargs)
            os._exit(0)
        else:                                               
            self.active_children.append(child_pid)

        return child_pid
```

In the two different Linux processes I derive from this class and then call e.g. something like:

```
self.fork(my_function, my_data)
```

However, I still get a couple of defunct python processes:

```
alexand+ 24777 24735  0 20:40 pts/29   00:00:00 [python3] <defunct>
alexand+ 24838 24733  0 20:40 pts/29   00:00:00 [python3] <defunct>
```

Maybe there is something I can change to avoid these defunct processes?

Comment: May be parent process got killed before killing all children. Are you sure all children are getting killed.

Comment: I am sure the parent processes do not get killed! They still run after they have started.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Process marked as `<defunct>` are called zombie processes. The system keeps them in that defunct state to allow their parent to read their status after they have finished running.

There are two ways to remove them:

- wait for them in the caller *shortly* after they have finished. The caller could setup a handler for SIGCHLD to be warned that one of its child have just ended, or simply poll them from time to time
- just ignore them. If the caller explicitely ignores SIGCHLD (`signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);`) at fork time, the childs will be immediately removed (no defunct state), but the parent has no more way to wait for them.

Comment: "but the parent has no more way to wait for them" -- Could you elaborate on why `Popen.wait()` will no longer work in this case? Does it internally use `signal.sigwait([signal.SIGCHLD])`?

Comment: @balu Yes it does, because it is the way allowed by the underlying OS.

Answer (score 1):

Children which exited are `<defunct>` until the parent waits for them.
Since you are calling *wait* in `reap_children()` only when you `fork()` a new child, the exited children stay `<defunct>` until the next child is forked. To get rid of them earlier, you could call `reap_children()` (i. e. *wait*) at earlier times. Normally, this is done through a handler for the SIGCHLD signal.